# Find formulas for the statements

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The task is: solve the following problems and justify your answers.

```
1. Find two formulas p and q such that p∧q is tautological.
2. Find two formulas p and q such that p∧q is contradictory.
3. Show that (p∧q)∧(r∧s) is not a tautology.
4. Show that ((p→q)→p)→p) is not a contradiction.
```

What I have is:

```
1. a) ((p∧q) → (q∧p))
   b) ((p∧q) ↔ (q∧p))
2. a) ((p∧q) ∞ (q∧p))
```

I did not find the second formula for the (2). I also didn`t understand how to solve such tasks. If just write any formula and check it with the truth table (as i did for these formalas I found) it can take hours. Is there another way to do that?

My question about the statements numer (3) and (4). Show means that I just need to write a table truth?

Comment: Truth table, or by substitution/formulas (or both).

Comment: Truth tables are certainly one way to prove a propositional formula is a tautology.  Could you be a little more explicit in your answers to parts 1 & 2 about which formula is x and which is y?

Comment: Could you please show how to prove (3) and (4) another way except truth table? cause I can onle do that via truth table.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the answers. I corrected it.

Comment: So, in answering parts 1 & 2, what are your formulas p and q?

Answer (score 2):

1. $p = a \lor \lnot a,\quad q= b \rightarrow b.\;$

   Then, since each of $p$ and $q$ are tautologies, so must $p \land q$ be a tautology.
2. $p = p, \quad q = \lnot p.\;$

   Then $p \land q \equiv p \land \lnot p \equiv \bot. \quad\;(\bot \;\text{means contradiction, or identically false.})$
3. We just need to find one truth-value assignment to $p, q, r, s$, respectively, that make the statement false. If there exist any such truth-value assignments , then by definition, the statement is not a tautology.

   Note that any one of the variables, when false, makes the entire statement false, irregardless of the truth-values of the other. Hence, the statement is not a tautology.
4. We need only find one truth-value assignment to $p, q, r, s$, respectively, that make the statement true. If there exists any such truth-value assignments, then by definition, the statement cannot be a contradiction.

   Hint: let $p$ be "false".

Comment: How does this not have an UV - +1